# Rails application planning, querying records by attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails application I have a Service model.  The service model has a string attribute called :code .

In my application I want to be able to display all Service objects that have the same code.

For example, if several Service object records have a :code of 8H4 I want to be able to list out all of those Service records that have the :code 8H4.

I am going to need to be able to do this for many different codes.

How do I implement this?  Do I need a different action in the controller for every code I want to use?  If so, would this make the controller too fat?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your controller create an action called show (or anything you want):

```
@services = Service.where(:code => '8H4')
```

and then in your view/show.html.erb you can list all those services:

```
 <% @services.each do |t| %>
     <%= t.code %>
 <% end %>
```

You don't need a different action each different code, maybe a variable instead.

```
@services = Service.where(:code => your-variable-here)
```

Comment: Would I need a different action for each unique code then?  I would probably call it something other than show in that case..but thank you this answers my question

Comment: No, you don't need, you can use a variable or something and then use it on your action.

Comment: Thanks..where/how would I pass in the code value to the variable?

Comment: It's better you explain us what you are trying to do, so we can help you in a better way. You can for instance, create a variable @code = '8H4' (anywhere because its global @), and place it where it says 'your-variable-here'.

Comment: Well I'll have a list of Service names on the webpage.  The user will click a name, which corresponds to a code.  After clicking I want to display a list of Service records that all have that same code.

Comment: you could always pass in the code through a route / param.  So @services = Service.where(:code => param[:code])

Comment: When inserting a variable into your-variable-here do I need quotations around the variable?